# DNS record mapping the hostnames and the external IP

Tags: azure, dns, wso2, mapping, azure-aks

So I'm deploying this app called WSO2 API Manager to AKS and at the end of the tutorial it asks me to do this :

> If the defined hostnames (in the previous step) are backed by a DNS
> service, add a DNS record mapping the hostnames and the external IP
> (EXTERNAL-IP) in the relevant DNS service.

So I don't know where to go from here, because if I map the DNS to the IP in the hosts file, the app works no problemo.
But I'm on AKS, if someone could guide me through doing the equivalent over there, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a DNS to work through the internet you need to properly configure it. If your DNS name is abc.com, first you need to purchase "abc.com" domain through a domain registrar. Then it should be mapped to the public IP of your Ingress. You can use Azure DNS for this. Refer to the following.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-getstarted-portal

Comment: Is there a way to access the application through the public IP without buying a DNS ?

Comment: Theoretically can. Can you access the server with the IP? I'm not sure whether Ingress requires SNI information to do routing. If so you will have to check how this can be done in Ingress and you will also have to do a few configuration changes in WSO2. But why adding a host entry is so difficult?

Comment: I don't know why I'm having troubles with this final step, to be honest I'm stuck, I can't access the server with the IP

Comment: If you don't want to purchase a TLD, Azure will allow you to create a `YOURAPP.cloudapp.azure.com` DNS record using the `service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-dns-label-name` service annotation. See [Apply a DNS label to the service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip#apply-a-dns-label-to-the-service).